# (iphone) How to change the server ip without shipping an updated application?

Tags: iphone, ip, domain-name

My application talks to my server and currently server's ip is embedded in the client application.

For any reason, I might have to change the server's location(and it's ip).
With current setup, I'll have to ship a new version with new server ip embedded.

I guess I could get a domain name and embed the domain name in the app, so that I can dynamically change the server machine(with domain name fixed).

Is there other options I could take?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **definitely** use DNS. Get a domain name, they are very inexpensive.

If for some reason you absolutely refused, you could devise a way to send a push notification to the phone for IP changes, but if a user has notifications off then you are out of luck.